# closest() not returning the closest label to my input

Tags: jquery, selector

I need to select the label which is above my input and get its text.

Sometimes it is like that :

```
<div id="q1">
    <label class="question_label">Label q1</label>
    <input type ="text">
</div>
```

Sometimes like that:

```
<div id="q2">
    <label class="question_label">Label q2</label>
    <br>
    <input type ="text">
</div>
```

I have tied with `prev()` but sometimes there is a `<br>` between the input and the label, so prev doesn't always work.
I also tried with `closest()` but it doesn't return the label:

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).closest('label').text());
});
```

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: You need to use `prev()` or `siblings()`, `closest()` search for ancestors not it's siblings

Comment: Use `$.("div label:first-child").text()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DO it like this: ( Tested and Verified. )

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().find('label').text());
});
```

Comment: no it doesn't work as sometimes prev() returns the <br>

Comment: `prev()` will be `<br>`

Comment: Working fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

The [closest](http://api.jquery.com/) finds the nearest parent element.

Use [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev) to get previous element:

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).prev('.question_label').text());
});
```

But you have `<br />` tag so you can use [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevall):

```js
    $(':input').each(function () {
        alert($(this).prevAll('.question_label').text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q2">
    <label class="question_label">Label q2</label>
    <br>
    <input type ="text">
</div>
```

Alternatively, you may use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) which selects the previous(all) or next(all) to the element.

Comment: thanks. But if I have several questions one after another, will prevAll return all the labels of all questions, not only the label of this question ?

Comment: yeah, prevAll returns all matching elements.

Comment: ok so that's not gonna work in my case as I want to get only the particular label associated with the input

Comment: @VincentTeyssier Use `.prevAll('.question_label').first()` to get just the nearest previous element.

Answer (score 3):

This will surely works for you

```
$(':input').each(function(index,$text){
    alert($(this).parent().find('label.question_label').text());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually if you modify your html then you can get exactly what you're trying to do:

```
<div id="q2">
    <label for="inputq2" class="question_label">Label q2</label>
    <br>
    <input type ="text" id="inputq2">
</div>
```

What I have done above is:

1. define the unique value for `for` in each of the label.
2. define the `id` in the input field exactly as in the label responding to it.

Now, do like this:

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    alert($('label[for="'+this.id+'"]').text());
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just remembered and answered another way.

Comment: better answer for me

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':text').each(function () {
    alert($(this).siblings('label').text());
});
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/ghe2e4q3/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(':input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().children("label").text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** is not the right choice for you, which search for ancestors and not it's siblings. So instead you can use **[`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)** or **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**

```js
console.log($(':input').prevAll('label').text());
console.log($(':input').siblings('label').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q2">
  <label class="question_label">Label q2</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(':input').each(function () {
            alert($(this).closest('div#q2').find('.question_label').text());
        });
    });


</script>



<body>

  <div id="q2">
    <label class="question_label">Label q2</label>
    <br>
    <input type ="text">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```